# Exclude any word followed by @ from regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to use the regex.replace function in VB.NET, and I want to exclude any word that has an @ symbol after it. At the moment, the pattern I'm using is "/b" & Term & "/b" (where Term is whatever word I want to replace).

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: That should be "\b" for a word-boundary, not "/b".

Comment: How do you expect to replace `@` if you don't use it on your regex?

Comment: Provide some example data - input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry, the '/b' was a typo. And I was asking what to include in the regex regarding the '@', that's why it's not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
\b(?<!@)[^@\s]+(?!@)\b
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DmbXb5/1)

Explanation

1. `[^@\s]+` This will exclude any word that has '@'within or just
   after it. character class [^] that starts with ^ indicates negate anything that is within the character class. Thus, ^ inside [] doesn't mean start of a string.
2. In many flavor The word boundary `\b` includes @ as a boundary value.
   Therefore you need to make sure that `\b` doesn't consider @ as a
   boundary. Therefore the lookahead and lookbehind has been introduced
   here.
3. The first `\b(?<!@)` ensures word boundary but not @
4. The last `(?!@)\b` ensures word boundy but not @

Comment: could you explain `[^@\s]+` in a bit more detail? `\s` is empty space yes? `^` denotes start of string, so you're saying match anything that starts with @ and is followed by white space at least one of more times?

Comment: @Bhargav I have updated the answer for you to have better understanding

Comment: @Bhargav : `^` only denotes the start of a string/line if it's _**not**_ inside square brackets: `[^ ]`. In that case it is a negated a character group, and will match anything **except** what's inside the square brackets. For instance, to match any character that is **not** `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`: `[^aeiou]`.

Comment: Thank you Vincent for the explanation